# NA in randomForest

Tags: r, regression, random-forest

I have a question regarding NA in randomForest (in R). I have a dataset which include both numerical and non-numerical variables, and the data includes some NA. Do anyone have some tips how to deal with this? I tried to use na.roughfix but then i get an error message "na.roughfix only works for numeric or factor". I also tried rfImpute but this does not work either because I have some NA in my response variable. Does anyone have som tips?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a snippet of your data so we can try to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Q is closed, but FWIW I've addressed these by replacing non-numeric columns with numerical representations of data.  e.g. I had a "Nationality" column that I replaced with "is_australian", "is_european", etc.  It's not a great solution but it seems to work for simple cases.

Comment: @Tim_Post: this question is not 'localized' at all! It's both general and important.

Comment: This helped me out over a year after it was closed for not being able to help others.